# Aurora mysql serverless 5.6 BIGINT unsigned column rounding after 16 digits

Tags: amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

For some reason when I insert a value to my Aurora serverless db cluster mysql 5.6, big int column it gets rounded after 16 digits.

Example:

- 734783792502575105 saves as 734783792502575100
- 9223372036854775807 saves as 9223372036854776000

My column is defined as -> bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL.

Isn't unsigned BIGINT supposed to be able to have a max value 18446744073709551615?

EDIT:

Even stranger is that I am able to insert 18446744073709551615 into the column but when I try to run a regular select on the table after the insert I start getting the following error:
"Value '18,446,744,073,709,551,615' is outside of valid range for type java.lang.Long"

I tested the queries in the Query Editor in the AWS dashboard and also through aws RDSDataService lib for nodejs.

Thx

Comment: How are you doing the insert? If you're using a client in a language like js that has limits on integer size, you might end up running into those limits -- e.g., `node -e 'console.log(734783792502575105)'` logs out 734783792502575100

Comment: @willis ..."I tested the queries in the Query Editor in the AWS dashboard and also through aws RDSDataService lib for nodejs."... The question is why I am not able to write the insert in their dashboard. If I do the same insert through PHPMyAdmin web interface against a regular MySQL DB, I don't encounter the problem.

Answer (score 1):

---

After running into this weird problem myself I found out that there is a setting in serverless-mysql to force bigInt into strings so the rounding error won't occur. It's on this page [mysql options](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options).

Here a snippet for setting the mysql config in nodeJS:

```
import mysql from 'serverless-mysql';

export const db = mysql({
  config: {
    // left out the normal stuff,
    supportBigNumbers: true,
    bigNumberStrings: true,
  },
});
```